# Sails.js waterline mongo id field

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to use `Sails.js` and `Waterline.js` to build an app on top of existing Mongo database.
The problem is that when I start the server it says

```
$ sails lift
error: Hook failed to load: orm
error: Error encountered while loading Sails core!
error: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: db.table.$id_1  dup key: { : null }
```

The `_id` field is a unique key on table. But it seems that `Waterline` tries to build an index on `id` field, that is not unique, and in some cases is equal to `null`.

First, I think that's very naughty to do something with database that I didn't explicitly asked for :-)

Second, what can I do about it? I cannot remove `id` key or substitute some values in there.

Maybe I missed some configuration options?

Comment: Can You post one of your model here? as that will explain the scenario better. And yes this is definitely a case of index created on null values.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't keep it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set autoPK to false in Model settings 
https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline#options

Comment: Greate, must have missed it. Thanks!